# WSDL in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I used worklight discover back-end service and used WSDL and it created adapter.

I am using public webservice just for test which is
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl

And after it creates adapter, I am just invoking it as Invoke Worklight Procedure, by passing two paramter (params, headers) like

```
{"GetCityWeatherByZIP": {"ZIP": "73105"}},{"SOAPAction": "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP"}
```

but it returns the result and says Zip code not found.

I have also read that worklight 6.1 has some issue with back-end service, Is that why I am having issue or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke the adapter in Worklight 6.1 one needs to change the payload to be:

```
{"tns:GetCityWeatherByZIP": {"tns:ZIP": "73105"}},{"SOAPAction": "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP"}
```

In Worklight 6.2 an improvement was made that removed the need to add the XML namespace prefixes in the payload